# Getting 'You provided undefined when a stream was expected' when server returns empty response

Tags: angular, observable, http-get

I'm working on an Angular v5 app, and just have this simple HTTP GET in my service:

`getData(param) {
    return this.http.get('/mydata?' + param)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }`

The problem is that when the server validly returns a 200 response with an empty result set (`[]`, meaning that no records were returned for the query), I get the following error:

`You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

I don't know where it could possible be getting "undefined" from. How do I handle this empty result use case without it throwing errors?